# Button Click - Hide Columns in between causes problems

Tags: excel, vba, hide

Good morning,

actually an easy thing but it brings problems.

I have two scenarios.

Scenario 1 - hides columns in the beginning & end (but not in between) - This works
Than i have a default button which shows all columns again, before and thats the plan, i can click another time on Button Scenario 2 but this time i have to hide columns **in between** and **this part doesnt work.**

Is this solvable or by logic itself not solvable? My approach was by an easy Makro in this case.

```
Sub Szenario2()
'
' Szenario2 Makro
'

'
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Range("B2").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("E:K").Select
    Range("E2").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("M:R").Select
    Range("M2").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("X:AM").Select
    Range("X2").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    Columns("X:AQ").Select
    Range("X2").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    Columns("X:AT").Select
    Range("X2").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("AV:BD").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("BH:BH").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("BK:BM").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("BR:BT").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("BZ:BZ").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("CE:CE").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 59
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 61
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 64
    Columns("CJ:CN").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 61
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 52
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 46
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub
```

In the end it shows me by activating Button Scenario 2 just the columns AU, BE, BF, BG. All of these shall actually belong to the selection but these are not all, the other ones are hided.

If i want to have my original table view first i have to click on scenario 1 and then on the default button.

Thanks for an approach.

PS

*Maybe this could cause the problem that 50% of the data is formated in a table and the other 50% of the data are not formated in a table?*

Comment: Try to be more adventurous"- (1) you don't need to `Select` anything in order to address it. (2) You don't need to scroll in order to go to a place to select it. (3) Once hidden, columns stay hidden until they are unhidden again. Therefore the toggle can only work if you hide some and unhide some at the same time. Therefore you should think in terms of ranges (to hide/unhide), not columns.

Answer (score 1):

This code will largely do what you want. You can call it in many different ways to fit your scenarios.

```
Private Sub HideColumns(ByVal Hide As Boolean, _
                        Optional ByVal Arr As Variant)

    Dim UsedRng         As Range            ' used range to show/hide from
    Dim Rng             As Range            ' range of columns to hide or show
    Dim i               As Integer          ' loop counter: Arr index
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' don't waste time on showing until you're done
    With ActiveSheet                        ' better name the sheet !
        With .UsedRange
            i = .Columns.Count + .Column    ' temporary, local use of this variable
        End With
        Set Rng = Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(i))
        Rng.Columns.Hidden = Hide           ' hide or unhide all columns
        
        If IsMissing(Arr) Then
            ' 'HideColumns True' will hide everything
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set Rng = .Columns(Arr(0))
            For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
                ' append all named columns to the range
                Set Rng = Application.Union(Rng, .Columns(Arr(i)))
            Next i
            Rng.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Hide
        End If
    End With
    
    ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=200
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True       ' display the result
End Sub
```

The procedure has 2 arguments, the second one optional. The first argument specifies what to do with ***all*** the columns, either hide them (=True) or not hide them (=False). Accordingly,  `HideColumns True` will hide everything and `HideColumns False` will show everything.

The second argument gives a list of columns. You can prepare the array using individual column IDs (like "AD") or column ranges (like "AD:AH"), comma separated, any number of columns. The fate of these columns will be the opposite of what the first argument says. If all columns are hidden, the listed ones will be the exception and vise versa.

In the end the sheet's first visible cell is scrolled into view and display, first above disabled, restored.

You should now prepare small procedures like the one shown below, each responding to one of your buttons and calling the same procedure with different (or missing) column arrays.

```
Private Sub Test_HideColumns()
    Dim Clms()      As String
    
    Clms = Split("AU,BE:BG", ",")
    HideColumns False, Clms
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Do i understand it right, that within the loop i have to add my Ranges within the code Set Rng = Application.Union(Rng, .Columns(Arr(i))) for i? And do i understand it right that the last small code you present should actually be sufficient? At least it looks like so i would start with this.

Comment: Yes, `Test_HideColumns` will be sufficient, and it's here that you specify the columns you want to hide or show. The procedure `HideColumns` shouldn't be touched. All adjustments are done from the caller and `HideColumns` acts upon the instruction received.